# How to change SwiftUI TextField style after tapping on it?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I changed TextField style like this:

```
TextField("Test", text: $name).textFieldStyle(CustomTextFieldStyle())
```

now I want it to change style when user taps on it.

My CustomTextFieldStyle is defined as:

```
  public struct CustomTextFieldStyle : TextFieldStyle {
    public func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .font(.callout)
            .padding(10)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                    .strokeBorder(SBGreen, lineWidth: 2))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
TextField("Test", text: $name).textFieldStyle(tapflag ? CustomTextFieldStyle1() : CustomTextStyle2())
```

do you have an example of your own TextStyle? Please, share it!

UPDATE

you are better to use some parameter with your style and bind it to "parent" View

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var editing = false
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Email", text: self.$email, onEditingChanged: { edit in
            self.editing = edit
        })
            .textFieldStyle(MyTextFieldStyle(focused: $editing)).font(.title).border(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct MyTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    @Binding var focused: Bool
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
        .padding(10)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                .stroke(focused ? Color.red : Color.gray, lineWidth: 3)
        ).padding()
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

the result looks like
[image]

Comment: @DanielKubicek máš aj nejaké iné info o TextFieldStyle protokole?

Comment: Does anybody else get a "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior" warning when using this solution? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 3):

Actual variant is

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomInput: View {
   @Binding var input: String
   @FocusState private var editing

   let width: CGFloat
   let placeholder: String

  var body: some View {
      TextField(
          "",
          text: $input,
          prompt: Text(placeholder)
      )
      .frame(width: width, height: 37)
      .textFieldStyle(BorderedStyle(focused: editing))
      .focused($editing)
      .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
      .keyboardType(.numberPad)
    }
 }


struct BorderedStyle: TextFieldStyle {
  var focused: Bool

  func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
      configuration
      .padding(10)
      .background(
          Rectangle()
              .stroke(
                  focused ? Color.red : Color.grey, lineWidth: 2
              )
      )
  }}
```