# Change style of TextField on focus (without a variable per field)

Tags: swiftui

I have a form with nested mini forms (for adding items) so you can add more items (thus adding more fields to the form dynamically). I would like to change the style of the field a user is currently typing on (the focus state).

I've seen some [solutions using state vars to keep track of each field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379010/how-to-change-swiftui-textfield-style-after-tapping-on-it), but since my fields are being added dynamically, keeping track of an unknown number of variables sounds like more trouble than it should be.

```swift
TextField("", text: $viewModel.item.name, onEditingChanged: {
     if $0 {
        //Put something here to change the border or background color directly, maybe reference to the field id or tag?
     }
 })
.modifier(TextInputStyle(isDisabled : false, isEditing: something)) // Or somehow pass a value here without having to make a state variable
```

**UPDATE**: Thanks to some help, I got closer, but now I'm getting some errors when programmatically disabling the field via a button (toggles `isDisabled`).

[image: Image of code with errors]

And in the console, I get this:

> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1864952 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1864952 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1864952 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1866776 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1865304 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1865304 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1862584 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1847528 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1847528 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1865304 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1878320 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1878200 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1878320 ===
> === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1878200 ===
> 2021-02-08 12:52:20.918323-0600 App [23659:862912] [SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Can you compare it against the text? If $viewModel.item.name.count > 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just abstract the `TextField` into its own component that does use a @State variable, but you'll only use it once and then reuse the component.

Minimal example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var disabled = false
    
    @State var text = "test" //these would come from your view model -- created multiple state for the text just for testing, but doesn't affect the highlighting behavior
    @State var text2 = "test2"
    @State var text3 = "test3"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HighlightableTextField(text: $text, disabled: disabled)
            HighlightableTextField(text: $text2, disabled: disabled)
            HighlightableTextField(text: $text3, disabled: disabled)
            
            Button(disabled ? "Enable" : "Disable") {
                disabled.toggle()
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct HighlightableTextField : View {
    @Binding var text : String
    var disabled : Bool
    @State private var isEditting = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: { editing in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                isEditting = editing
            }
        })
        .disabled(disabled)
        .background(isEditting ? Color.red : Color.clear)
    }
}
```

I'm using @State vars for the text bindings, but that could still be linked to your view model, like your original code. Also, I'm choosing to only pass in the `String` binding, but obviously you could pass in any other parameters you need as well.

Comment: After some testing, I'm getting a warning on the `isEditing = $0` line: "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior." and a bunch of messages in the console that look like this: === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1850392 ===. I'll update my question

Comment: Okay -- I will look for the update This doesn't happen during my testing. Is this using my code or the version of it that you modified for your use?

Comment: Thanks. The issues arose when I added a button that toggles the field so it will be enabled or disabled.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it on my end after experimentation adding a disabled property and have updated my code. Call `isEditing` on the next run loop with `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: Thanks, for all the help. I still get the console warnings :=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1877176 === but that has something to do with toggling `.disabled(isDisabled)`. When I comment out that line, no errors or warnings. Oh well...

Comment: In your code, or mine? I'm not seeing that in my *updated* example, but it's possible you're doing something different (like whatever is happening with `handler`)

Comment: It's in my code, but after incorporating the `DispatchQueue.main.async`. To reproduce, enable the field (isDisabled = false), tap on the field and immediately tap the button to disable (isDisabled = true). The text field needs to be active while you disable it to see the warnings. The other errors are gone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228435/discussion-between-jnpdx-and-coopersita).

Answer (score 0):

I have created custom textfield view, So, its reusable....

```
struct TextFieldView: View {
    
    @State var textField1 = "A"
    @State var textField2 = "B"
    @State var textField3 = "C"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(value: $textField1)
            CustomTextField(value: $textField2)
            CustomTextField(value: $textField3)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

// TestField struct separation
struct CustomTextField : View {
    // Bind textfield string input value 
    @Binding var value : String
    // Manage focus point indication
    @State private var isFocused = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                .stroke(isFocused ? Color.blue : Color.gray.opacity(0.4), lineWidth: 2)
            TextField("", text: $value, onEditingChanged: {
                isFocused = $0
            }).padding()
        }
        .frame(height: 50)
        .padding()
    }
}
```